# rails -theme sb admin bootstrap theme

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have a rails application and i want integrate this layout

http://startbootstrap.com/sb-admin

I have boostrap install and i have no problem, but when i try to copy and paste this layout in my application i have a problem with .less and also(i think with js).
How i can integrate this theme?

one of my errors is that :

> File to import not found or unreadable: twitter/bootstrap/reset.less.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the less gem installed? http://rubygems.org/gems/less